# AngularJS validations form on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am having trouble on making validations from fields coming from a ng-repeat. Once I satisfy an error, every field with the same is as well satisfied. Is there any other way to do this? Like using the ng-model as validation indicator instead of name?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate >
   <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="fieldname" placeholder="Enter mobile number" required>
      <span ng-hide="!myForm.fieldname.$error.required">THIS FIELD IS REQUIRED {{ myForm.fieldname.$error.required }}</span>
      <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
   </fieldset>
   <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button> 

   <div id="choicesDisplay">
      {{ choices }}
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}, {id: 'choice2'}];

    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
      var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
      $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
    };

    $scope.removeChoice = function() {
      var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
      $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
    };

});
```

PS.

I am aware that this can be done by manipulating the name attribute of the input with incremental but I was wondering if this can be done with less effort

Comment: I would use `choice.id` or `choice.name` as a `name ` property. I don't see any other option. In order make validation work you need to have different names of the fields.

Comment: Ok thanks looks like, just testing my luck if there is any other choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate >
   <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" data-ng-form="nestedMyForm" >
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="fieldname" placeholder="Enter mobile number" required>
      <span ng-hide="!nestedMyForm.fieldname.$error.required">THIS FIELD IS REQUIRED {{ nestedMyForm.fieldname.$error.required }}</span>
      <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
   </fieldset>
   <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button> 

   <div id="choicesDisplay">
      {{ choices }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Check how I added data-ng-form="nestedMyForm" hope that should work

Comment: @Dean Christiam Armada (thumbsup) :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without adding a increment on the name field. 
You can do it easily with something like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="fieldname_{{$index}}" required>
```

Comment: You were faster :) wanted to give the same answer

Comment: <span ng-hide="!myForm.fieldname_{{ $index }}.$error.required">THIS FIELD IS REQUIRED {{ myForm.fieldname.$error.required }}</span>

will this be the code for this part as well?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but did not work. Making the name dynamic does not detect the validation properly. weird.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick - notice how i changed the field name to be -  field+$index so we can tell the difference betweeen each iteration inside the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">   <form name="myForm" novalidate >    <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" ng-init="vm.name='field'+$index" name="{{vm.name}}" placeholder="Enter mobile number" required>
      <span ng-hide="!myForm.{{vm.name}}.$error.required">THIS FIELD IS REQUIRED {{ myForm.{{vm.name}}.$error.required }}</span>
      <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>    </fieldset>    <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button> 

   <div id="choicesDisplay">
      {{ choices }}    </div> </div>
```